# Unhandled Runtime Error: No router instance found in Next.js with Apollo Client

Tags: next.js, next-router

I'm encountering an issue with my Next.js and Apollo Client application. When handling GraphQL errors and trying to navigate to the login page, I receive the following error in the console:

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: No router instance found.
You should only use "next/router" on the client side of your app.
src\apollo\withApollo.tsx (18:8) @ Router
```

I'm using the **`onError`** link from Apollo Client to handle GraphQL errors. When a "not authenticated" error occurs, I'm attempting to use Next.js's **`Router.push("/login")`** to navigate to the login page. However, I'm getting the error mentioned above.

```
"next": "13.5.2",
```

```
import { onError } from "@apollo/client/link/error";
import Router from "next/router";

const ErrorLink = onError(({ graphQLErrors, networkError }) => {
  if (graphQLErrors)
    graphQLErrors.map(({ message, locations, path }) => {
      console.log(
        `[GraphQL error]: Message: ${message}, Location: ${locations}, Path: ${path}`
      );
      if (
        message.includes("not authenticated") &&
        typeof window !== "undefined"
      ) {
        Router.push("/login");
      }
    });
  if (networkError) console.log(`[Network error]: ${networkError}`);
});
```

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```